# tf.estimator.Estimator gives different test accuracy when trianed epoch by epoch vs over all epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have defined a straightforward CNN as my model_fn for a tf.estimator.Estimator and feed it with this input_fn:

> ```
> def input_fn(features, labels, batch_size, epochs):
>     dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features))
>     dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.cond(tf.random_uniform([], 0, 1) > 0.5, lambda: dataset_augment(x), lambda: x),
>                           num_parallel_calls=16).cache()
>     dataset_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((labels))
>     dataset = dataset.zip((dataset, dataset_labels))
>     dataset = dataset.shuffle(30000)
>     dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs)
>     dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
>     dataset = dataset.prefetch(-1)
>     return dataset
> ```

when I train the estimator this way, I get 43% test accuracy after 10 epochs:

```
steps_per_epoch = data_train.shape[0] // batch_size
for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    cifar100_classifier.train(lambda: input_fn(data_train, labels_train, batch_size, epochs=1), steps=steps_per_epoch)
```

But when I train it this way I get 32% test accuracy after 10 epochs:

```
steps_per_epoch = data_train.shape[0] // batch_size
max_steps = epochs * steps_per_epoch
cifar100_classifier.train(steps=max_steps,
                              input_fn=lambda: input_fn(data_train, labels_train, batch_size, epochs=epochs))
```

I just cannot understand why these two methods produce different results. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: How are tog setting up `cifar100_classifier`? My guess is that it has to do with the hyperparameters being reset in the first case.

Comment: @McAngus I am creating my model with tf.keras.layers and use AdamOptimizer to train it. And I assume checkpoints keep the state of both optimizers and weights and biases of layers. So training a model in one go would have the same effect as loading from saved checkpoints at the end of each epoch and continuing training for another epoch and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling the `input_fn` multiple times in the first example it seems like you would be generating more augmented data through `dataset_augment(x)` as you're doing an augmentation coin-toss for every `x` every epoch.

In the second example you only do these coin-tosses once and then train multiple epochs on that same data. So here your train set is effectively ``smaller''.

The `.cache()` doesn't really save you from this in the first example.

Comment: You could actually try to remove `.cache()` from the `input_fn` and see if doesn't lead to augmentation being called every epoch in both formulations, I'm not 100% on how map interacts with repeat exactly.

Answer (score 0):

are your model's weights initialized randomly? this may be a case.

Comment: I am using tf.keras.layers and not setting anything manually. But how does this affect my training? Isn't a tf.estimator.Estimator object loaded from the saved checkpoints (with the weights and variables calculated till that point) and continue from that point on if you loop over epochs?

Comment: When the nn initializes the weights for the first time it uses some initialization methods, thats why you cant have same outputs in different executions.The default kernel_initializer for a Conv2d e.g. is 'glorot_uniform' as you can see in the source code here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/62d097c4ff6fa694a4dbc670e9c7eb9e2bc27c74/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L424 . here is some information about this initializer:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer . You can try adding another initializer and set a seed value.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem :) problem is not having different results across different runs.